# Can i set minimum and maximum words in a sentence to split the text file using nltk tokenizer?

Tags: python, string, nlp, nltk

This is how i am converting large text file into sentences

```
import nltk.data

tokenizer = nltk.data.load("tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle")
text_file = """
CHARACTER. EXPANSION. GROWTH AND PRIDE!
CHARACTER. EXPANSION. GROWTH AND PRIDE!
DIG DEEP! Find that strength that lives inside you. """
splitting_into_smaller = tokenizer.tokenize(text_file)
print(splitting_into_smaller)
```

```
output:
['\nCHARACTER.', 'EXPANSION.', 'GROWTH AND PRIDE!', 'CHARACTER.', 'EXPANSION.', 'GROWTH AND PRIDE!', 'DIG DEEP!', 'Find that strength that lives inside you.']
```

each word is taken as a sentence
is there a way we can set minimum and maximum characters for sentences?
so that output can be something like this?

```
['\nCHARACTER, EXPANSION, GROWTH AND PRIDE!', 'CHARACTER, EXPANSION, GROWTH AND PRIDE!', 'DIG DEEP ,Find that 
strength that lives inside you.']
```

any help is much appreciated
thanks in advance!

i tried using spacy but it's a tad bit slow and still doesn't solve the issue i believe, didn't get to play around with much

Answer (score 0):

You have loaded tokenizer that is created to tokenize on sentences and punctuation (as your output shows).
What you expect is a tokenizer that tokenizes on new lines.

There might be one that works this way.

Or, you might preprocess your text so that you replace your punctuation to some neutral characters and then replace newline symbols to punctuation. In this way you would prepare data so that your selected tokenizer would work as you expected.

```py
import nltk.data

tokenizer = nltk.data.load("tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle")
text_file = """CHARACTER. EXPANSION. GROWTH AND PRIDE!
CHARACTER. EXPANSION. GROWTH AND PRIDE!
DIG DEEP! Find that strength that lives inside you. """

# Added this line
text_file = text_file.replace('.',' ').replace('!',' ').replace('  ',' ').replace('\n','.\n')

splitting_into_smaller = tokenizer.tokenize(text_file)
print(splitting_into_smaller)
print(set(splitting_into_smaller))
```

Results in

```
['CHARACTER EXPANSION GROWTH AND PRIDE .', 'CHARACTER EXPANSION GROWTH AND PRIDE .', 'DIG DEEP Find that strength that lives inside you']
{'DIG DEEP Find that strength that lives inside you', 'CHARACTER EXPANSION GROWTH AND PRIDE .'}
```